How to show the following matrix has eigenvalues $-d,-d+1,...,d$?
Consider the following $(2d+1)\times (2d+1)$ matrix:
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 
0 &\frac{2d}{2} & 0 &0 & \cdots &0 & 0 \\ 
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{2d-1}{2} &0& \cdots & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & \frac{2}{2} &0 & \frac{2d-2}{2} &\cdots & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & \frac{3}{2} & 0 &\cdots &0 & 0\\ 
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots & \ddots &\vdots &\vdots\\ 
0 &0 &0 &0 &\cdots &0 & 1/2 \\ 
0 &0 &0 &0 &\cdots &\frac{2d}{2} & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
How can one show that $A$ has eigenvalues $-d, -d+1,...,d$?

Also, it looks like $A$ is of size $(2d+1)×(2d+1).$   So, it defines a linear transformation from $\Bbb R^{2d+1}$ to itself, say.

This question was on the Alibaba 2024 qualifying round. The qualifying round has now ended. I think it is okay that this question is now posted to MO, though I'm not sure.

This is known as the Sylvester-Kac matrix and related forms.

This and many similar matrices are discussed in Muir's book "A Treatise on the Theory of Determinants".

This looks like the matrix representing the sum of a simple root vector and its opposite in an irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$

You hope to show for each $n$ that the $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ matrix
$$
B_n = \begin{pmatrix} 
0 &n & 0 &0 & \cdots &0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & n-1 &0& \cdots & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 2&0 & n-2 &\cdots & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 3 & 0 &\cdots &0 & 0\\ 
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots & \ddots &\vdots &\vdots\\ 
0 &0 &0 &0 &\cdots &0 & 1 \\ 
0 &0 &0 &0 &\cdots &n & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
has eigenvalues $-n,2-n,\dots,n-2,n$ (your matrix is related by $A=\frac12B_{2d}$).
Recall that there is a $(n+1)$-dimensional representation $\varphi\colon\mathfrak{sl}_2\to \mathfrak{gl}_{n+1}(\mathbb C)$ of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ given by
$$\begin{align*}
\varphi(e)&=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 &n & 0 &0 & \cdots &0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & n-1 &0& \cdots & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0&0 & n-2 &\cdots & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots &0 & 0\\ 
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots & \ddots &\vdots &\vdots\\ 
0 &0 &0 &0 &\cdots &0 & 1 \\ 
0 &0 &0 &0 &\cdots &0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}\\
\varphi(h)&=\begin{pmatrix} 
n &0 & 0 &0 & \cdots &0 & 0 \\ 
0 & n-2 &0 &0& \cdots & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0&n-4 & 0 &\cdots & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots &0 & 0\\ 
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots & \ddots &\vdots &\vdots\\ 
0 &0 &0 &0 &\cdots &2-n & 0 \\ 
0 &0 &0 &0 &\cdots &0 & -n 
\end{pmatrix}\\
\varphi(f)&=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 &0 & 0 &0 & \cdots &0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 &0& \cdots & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 2&0 & 0 &\cdots & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 3 & 0 &\cdots &0 & 0\\ 
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots & \ddots &\vdots &\vdots\\ 
0 &0 &0 &0 &\cdots &0 & 0 \\ 
0 &0 &0 &0 &\cdots &n & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}$$
Thus, $B_n$ is simply $\varphi(e+f)$. But $e+f$ and $h$ are conjugate under the adjoint action of $\mathrm{SL}_2$ on $\mathfrak{sl}_2$. Thus $B_n$ is conjugate to $\varphi(h)$. But the eigenvalues of $\varphi(h)$ are clearly $-n,2-n,\dots,n-2,n$.

Can you explain the notations $\mathfrak{sl}2$ and $\mathfrak{gl}{n+1}(\mathbb C)$, and also what "the adjoint action of $\mathrm{SL}_2$ on $\mathfrak{sl}_2$" is?

The Lie group $\mathrm{SL}_2$ has the tautological $2$-dimensional representation $V$, so $\mathrm{Sym}^nV$ is a $(n+1)$-dimensional representation. This is a group homomorphism $\mathrm{SL}2\to\mathrm{GL}{n+1}$, whose derivative is the Lie algebra homomorphism $\mathfrak{sl}2\to \mathfrak{gl}{n+1}$ in my answer.

Thank you for your response. However, I know next to nothing about Lie groups and algebras, and I don't know what $\text{Sym}^n V$ stands for. Can the eigenvectors here be simply described?

@IosifPinelis Think of your matrices as operators on the space of all homogeneous polynomials $h(x,y)$ of degree $n$. Then, in the monomial basis, $B_n$ is the operator $x\frac\partial{\partial y}+y\frac\partial{\partial x}$ (this is one possible realization of the $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-irrep). The $\lambda$-eigenfunctions for this operator are $\left(\frac{x+y}{x-y}\right)^{\frac\lambda2}F(x^2-y^2)$, with $F$ any function. So one just examines for which $\lambda$ can one obtain polynomials.

@მამუკაჯიბლაძე : Thank you for your comment. Can you expand its last sentence, maybe in a formal answer? I think it would be useful to know the eigenvectors more or less explicitly.

@IosifPinelis OK done

As requested by Iosif Pinelis, here is another version of the (perfectly correct, in my opinion) answer by Kenta Suzuki.
Let $V$ be the $d+1$-dimensional vector space of homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ in variables $x$, $y$. Then the matrix $B_n$ from that answer is the matrix of the operator $T=x\frac\partial{\partial y}+y\frac\partial{\partial x}$ in the monomial basis $x^d$, $x^{d-1}y$, ..., $xy^{d-1}$, $y^d$. In variables $x+y=u$, $x-y=v$ the operator $T$ is $u\frac\partial{\partial u}-v\frac\partial{\partial v}$, with $T(u^iv^j)=(i-j)u^iv^j$, so monomials in $u$, $v$ form an eigenbasis, with eigenvalues $d$, $d-2$, ..., $2-d$, $-d$.

Very nice, and quite elementary! Is there a book covering such techniques?

@IosifPinelis There are some questions here and on math.SE with some literature suggestions in answers, https://mathoverflow.net/q/123745/41291 https://mathoverflow.net/q/335116/41291 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4351990/214353
